# Quarkus: no tenant identifier specified when using multitenant=DATABASE

Tags: hibernate, multi-tenant, quarkus

I'm trying to implement multi-tenancy with Quarkus as described [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm). I added
`quarkus.hibernate-orm.multitenant=DATABASE` to `application.properties` file and implemented `io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.tenant.TenantResolver`. But when I try to use `EntityManager` I get this exception:

`org.hibernate.HibernateException: SessionFactory configured for multi-tenancy, but no tenant identifier specified`

and my `TenantResolver` implementation is not used. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like that inside the lambda the CDI based TenantResolver is not available. Maybe you should create a new [issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/) to do further investigation. You can add me in the comment (@michael-schnell) and I will take a look.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @user1482309, this feature is not intended to be used with AWS Lambda. So, if you need multitenancy inside AWD Lambda, then you have to implement it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not use AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, however I'm not sure it is the best practice. I'd appreciate if anyone points out whether there is some problem with this approach:

I had a similar issue when trying to use multi-tenancy with Quarkus inside a multithread "ExecutorService" Java Lambda function.

It seems the problem is not the use of Lambda function, but the use of multiple threads. When debugging, it is possible to identify that the method:

```
 

    io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.tenant.HibernateCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver.resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier()
```

cannot get the current active request context when it's called from a multithread code, and therefore returns a null value for the tenantId

I managed to work around this by activating the context manually when the thread starts, using:

```
Arc.container().requestContext().activate();
```

Here's the snippet:

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(120);

for (int i = 0; i < datasources.length; i++) {
    final Integer j = new Integer(i);
    threadPool.execute(() -> {

        //activates request context
        Arc.container().requestContext().activate();

        //here goes the rest of the thread code. In some point of it, it is necessary to obtain the tenant identifier
        // (...)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create fake default datasource, example:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind = postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username = 1
quarkus.datasource.password = 1
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url = 1
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion. I have default datasource. I'm afraid the problem is that I'm trying to use `TenantResolver` inside lambda.